SKU in Woocommerce displays the text 1/4 as a fraction
We have a Variation SKU: W-250-1/4 (the 1/4 represents lifting speed) however Woocommerce convert the text to a fraction please see Image 1 (shows Variable SKU):

and Image 2 how it is displayed:

The weird thing it does not do that to any of the other Lifting Speed ones i.e. W-250-2/8 and W-250-3/12.
Is there any way we can stop Woocoomerce from converting text to fractions?
In the interim, the only thing I can do is to put spaces between i.e. 1 / 4 , but this is not inline with all our documentation.

Best guess this is wptexturize, but I can't look in detail right now. See a similar problem on WPSE where it looked like we had to disable texturize completely.

Actually can you double check what you're getting in the HTML please? Is it the symbol ¼ as a character, or as an &-something entity ? That would make it easier to find in the WordPress / WooCommerce code. (It may even be some other plugin or theme, trying to be helpful.) Can you find whatever it's inserting in your site code somewhere?

It is in the SKU and if I look at the code is displays as follows: https://freeimage.host/i/dHn71DJ

I have tried to add this code to my functions.php and it does not work: add_filter('run_wptexturize', '__return_false');

Right, no, you can see in the view source screenshot that WordPress has written it correctly in the HTML. I’m not sure what’s left: your browser might be doing this, or a script on the page, or possibly even the font you’re using (?). Does this happen on all devices? Does it still happen if you temporarily use a different theme? If you write 1/4 somewhere else on a different page does that become a fraction too?
